# How to automatically colour cell background with value selected from custom dropdown list in MS Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

In MS Excel 2010 Professional is there a way to automatically copy the background colour of the custom dropdown values from somewhere else in a spreadsheet?

I have some Data Validation on a row of cells that comes from two custom cells which have a background:

[image]

A53 and A54 look like this:

[image]

When selecting from the dropdown in my SS how can I configure it so that it turns green or red and not just populates with the text?

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Data validation will not change formatting of the cells. You will need to use `Conditional Formatting` to do what you desire.

Once you have your lists in place, apply conditional formatting rules to those cells which use a formula that checks for the words `RESTRICT` and `CASCADE`.

1. Select the cells with the lists
2. Create a new conditional formatting rule
3. Choose `Use formula to determine which cells to format`
4. Add the formula `=D1="CASCADE"` *(D1 will be the first cell in the
   group you selected)*
5. Click the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button and choose the green fill
   [image]
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> twice.

You will do the same for the `RESTRICT` text with red formatting. When you are done you will have two rules.

[image]

You will notice the `Applies to` window will show the cells the rules are applied to *(in this example I used the entire D column; `$D:$D`)*. You do not need to create a formula for each row, the rule does it for you automatically.

Now when I make a selection from a list in column D, it automatically formats is according to the rules we created.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I'm having difficulty making the dropdown show up. I have changed my spreadsheet around and now it is column B that I want to control, which leaves me with this setup: http://imgur.com/neyttpt . However, when I select anything in column B I don't see a visible dropdown. When you say `Select the cells with the lists` - are you saying to highlight column B in my case? Edit: What I _have_ just noticed is that when I **type** 'YES' into any cell in column B it turns it green, same with 'NO'. Just no dropdown...

Comment: The lists and the conditional formatting are two different things. The conditional formatting is based off where you place the lists. This means you have to create the lists by using Data Validation in column B like you did in the example in your question.